# How can I remove a WooCommerce Product Tab's sub section in wp-admin?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

WooCommerce settings are located at `wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings` and each of the Tabs for its settings is a continuation of the URL query string (ex: `wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=products` for Products).

I know how to use the `woocommerce_settings_tabs_array` hook to manipulate the tab itself, but these Tabs also have sub links called "Sections."

For example, Products has General, Inventory, Downloadable Products and Product Vendors for me since I have a premium plugin.

How do I remove these sections from underneath the tab? Specifically, I want to remove the Product Vendors link that that premium extension added.

Answer (score 2):

[image: WooCommerce settings with product tab]

To change this "sub navigation" you could use the WooCommerce filter "[woocommerce_get_sections_products](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-a-section-to-a-settings-tab/)".

The following example code will remove the sub navigation point "inventory":

```
function change_navi_function($sections)
{
    // remove sub navigation point "inventory"
    unset($sections['inventory']);

    return $sections;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_sections_products', 'change_navi_function');
```

[image: WooCommerce settings with product tab without the subnavigation point inventory]

What you have to do now is either to hook your "change_navi_function" function after the function from the premium plugin and then remove the "Product Vendors" from the "$sections" array. Or you unhook the function from the premium plugin which use the "woocommerce_get_sections_products" filter.

Answer (score -1):

you can find the file in 
`~/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/views/html-admin-settings.php`

```
foreach ( $tabs as $slug => $label ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_html( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=' . esc_attr( $slug ) ) ) . '" class="nav-tab ' . ( $current_tab === $slug ? 'nav-tab-active' : '' ) . '">' . esc_html( $label ) . '</a>';
}
```

and edit `html-admin-settings.php` add code

```
foreach ( $tabs as $slug => $label ) {
    if( $slug != "Product"){
        echo '<a href="' . esc_html( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=' . esc_attr( $slug ) ) ) . '" class="nav-tab ' . ( $current_tab === $slug ? 'nav-tab-active' : '' ) . '">' . esc_html( $label ) . '</a>';
    }   
}
```

Comment: You should never change a core file, also plugin core. What is after an update of the plugin?

Comment: I can't update this website ,because it is unimaginable.

Comment: @user141080     's solution can't work